# I need help using the "==" in this solution

Tags: c++

The function `contains(Object obj)` returns true even though an object of that value is not in the pointer array. I have tried to overload the "==" function in my class `Rec`. It is using the function but the results are not what I want.

This is an attempt at a solution to a homework problem.

Design a class template, `Collection`, that stores a collection of `Objects` (in an array), along with the current size of the collection. Provide public functions `isEmpty`, `makeEmpty`, `insert`, `remove`, and `contains`. `contains(x)` returns `true` if and only if an `Object` that is equal to `x` is present in the collection.

I have tried other ways but I can't use `nullptr` as assignment.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename Object>

class Collection {
public:
    int ndx = 0;
    Object *data[10] = { nullptr };
    void insert(Object obj) {
        if (ndx == 10) {
            cout << "Container is full!!" << endl;
        }
        else {
            data[ndx] = &obj;
            //cout << data[ndx]->area() << endl;
            ++ndx;
            cout << "Inserted in Location: " << ndx - 1 << endl;
        }
    }
    void isEmpty() {
        if (ndx > 0) {
            cout << "Not empty " << ndx << " items!" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Is empty, " << ndx << " items!" << endl;
        }
    }
    void makeEmpty() {
        for (int i = 0; i < ndx; i++)
            data[i] = nullptr;
        ndx = 0;
        cout << "It is Empty!" << endl;
    }
    void remove(Object obj) {
        cout << obj.area() << "here" << endl;
        int index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < ndx; i++) {
            if (data[i] == obj) {
                index = i;
            }
        }
        if (index != -1) {
            if (index == ndx - 1)
                --ndx;
            else {
                for (int i = index; i < ndx; i++) {
                    data[i] = data[i + 1];
                }
                --ndx;
                data[ndx] = nullptr;
            }
            cout << "Object Removed Location: " << index << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Object not found!" << endl;
        }
    }
    bool contains(Object obj) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ndx; i++) {
            if (data[i] == obj) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

};
class Rec {
public:
    int width;
    int hieght;
    void setValues(int &w, int &h) {
        width = w;
        hieght = h;
    }
    void setWidth(int &w) {
        width = w;
    }
    void setHieght(int &h) {
        hieght = h;
    }
    int area() { return width * hieght; };
    bool operator==(const Rec& rhs)const {
        cout << "used Normal" << endl;
        return (width == rhs.width) && (hieght == rhs.hieght);
    }
};
bool operator==(Rec * lhs, Rec rhs) {
    cout << "used *" << endl;
    return (lhs->width == rhs.width) && (lhs->hieght == rhs.hieght);
}
int main()
{
    Collection<Rec> test;
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        Rec r;
        r.setValues(i, i);
        test.insert(r);
    }
    Rec r;
    int i = 22;
    r.setValues(i, i);
    bool t = test.contains(r);
    cout << "Here?: " << t << endl;
    r.setValues(i, i);
    test.remove(r);
    test.makeEmpty();
    //cout << test.data[6]->area() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I want it to return false.

Comment: First issue I can see is `data[ndx] = &obj;` in insert function. You are storing pointer to a local variable in member variable of class. After insert function is finished that pointer no longer points to valid memory.

Comment: Your `isEmpty` function should return a `bool` value so that code outside your class can determine if the container is empty.  Writing to `cout` won't help in an `if` statement.

Comment: You need to decide who owns the memory pointed to by the `data` array elements.  The `makeEmpty` function needs to `delete` memory if it is allocated from the heap.

Comment: Hint:  The `std` containers *copy* an item into the container; they don't use pointers.

Comment: Ashwani, so the data[ndx] pointer needs to be changed after insert? How?

Comment: Thomas Mathews, I can solve this without pointers by logically removing data elements without deleting and overwriting. I am trying to do it with deleting.

Comment: Thomas Mathews, Yes the isEmpty should be a bool, but I think the instructions imply void.